# Pressing the button for another job at the same time the sensor will constantly print the data on the screen (x=raw.input())

Tags: python

How do I get the sensor to continuously measure and press the screen, whether I command the pi-car for its movements at the same time? The measurement is taken once and waiting for me to enter a command.But I want the measurement to continue even if I don't enter a command

Comment: This is far too broad/vague, and likely off-topic. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Pi ≠ Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new on the site, sorry if the question is wrong